# jQuery Navigation - Help Needed

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am working on a [site](http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com) with a fairly large accordion style navigation (it does not use the accordion UI).

There are four sub-menu sections that toggle open when clicked. I have the active link highlighted. The one remaining step is to keep the current active sub-menu open when on a page within the sub-menu. I can keep it open when I am working with static pages, but on this site the navigation is an includes file and therefore I need some help working out a dynamic way to keep those sections open.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('ul#menu3 ul').hide();                
$('ul#menu3 > li > a.drop').click(function(){
$(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
   return false;
   });                      
});
</script>
```

Basically what I need is some way to apply a class to the active group so that it will show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using to solve the problem:

```
$(function(){
$('#mainContentTabs').tabs();
$('#subContentTabBoxes').tabs();
$('.interior #subContent > ul > li > a.drop').click(function(){
$(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
     return false;
});

$(window).ready(function() {
$('li.products ul').show();
    $('li.technical ul').show();
    $('li.tips ul').show();
$('li.quicklinks ul').show();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the submenu animation in a function, so to call the submenu in, you use on your a href

```
onclick="showSubMenu('id')"
```

That function would handle the sliding in. Then once clicked onto a page that requires a submenu to appear, simply add to the end of your page a small

```
<script>document.ready(function() {showSubMenu('parent-id')});</script>
```

Hope this helps.

C

Comment: Hi Chris, this is getting warm, however this requires manual coding of each page and since the footer is also an includes file, this will be more than problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to apply the class dynamically either as a variable or on the element it self. e.g.

```
var page = 'ul#menu3';
```

Then use this variable to trigger the initial state e.g.

```
$('#ul#menu3').show();
```

This would would need to run before all the other javascript relating to the dropdowns

Comment: Hi Matpol, alas, #ulmenu3 is currently visible. The sub-layers are hidden on purpose and I only want them to show when clicked or when a sub-menu item is the active page. Thanks.

Comment: so change the page var to be the element you want to show on the page as I say this needs to be dynamic and will change depending on which page you are on.